# aggregating by pre-existing time intervals in R

Tags: r, aggregate, intervals

I have the following data - it is an aggregated json feed of bike availability at one citibike station taken at 10-minute intervals over one month. I have successfully separated the date from the time using 
`data$time<- format(data$created_at,"%H:%M:%S")` but am not sure how to proceed from there for summary statistics at each interval without a time-consuming aggregation of each one separately.

```
> head(data)
              id station_id status available_bike_count available_dock_count
28847606 3801486        295 Active                   33                   34
28847938 3801818        295 Active                   37                   30
28848270 3802150        295 Active                   34                   33
28848602 3802482        295 Active                   36                   31
28848934 3802814        295 Active                   33                   34
28849266 3803146        295 Active                   32                   35
                  created_at station_summary_id month year     day
28847606 2013-10-01 00:00:00              11641    10 2013 Tuesday
28847938 2013-10-01 00:10:00              11642    10 2013 Tuesday
28848270 2013-10-01 00:20:00              11643    10 2013 Tuesday
28848602 2013-10-01 00:30:00              11644    10 2013 Tuesday
28848934 2013-10-01 00:40:00              11645    10 2013 Tuesday
28849266 2013-10-01 00:50:00              11646    10 2013 Tuesday
> dim(data)
[1] 4267   10
```

The output should be a data.frame with 144 rows for each interval with 3 extra columns for mean, median, and mode of `available_bike_count` but only intervals that fall on weekdays(Mon - Fri) should be included.   The data.frame should look like this:

```
head(output)
  interval     mean    median      mode
1 00:00:00 11.19383 11.729039  6.832517
2 00:10:00 10.94193  9.873530  9.161699
3 00:20:00 19.58576  5.386799  1.271674
4 00:30:00 10.06028 15.003440  6.306354
5 00:40:00 11.33270  2.041195 12.506719
```